# Overriding Elementor Defaults with Custom CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox, overriding, elementor

I've been trying to create a navbar using elementor with my own custom stylesheet. I am using flexbox for the nav menu and can't seem to get rid of the left/right margin. I want my 'main-nav ul' to be the same width as its parent ('.main-nav'). As you can see in devtools the div is getting a max-width of 500 which is creating the margins but I don't know how to get rid of that max-width. Even me targeting it in my stylesheet doesn't override it.
Any help???

Following images for reference! :)

[devtools max-width toggle on] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vom9.png

[devtools max-width toggle off] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzVLF.png

[fail to override with custom css] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM4aG.png

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post some code so we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
max-width: 1030px!important
```

Comment: I'd expect that elementor/frontend/before_enqueue_styles hook worked by overwriting Elementor style without !important, but it didn't.